# How to change background color of react-day-picker?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-day-picker

I would like to change the background color of the day picker but I can't seem to find a way.
Here is my code:

```
.DayPicker-wraper {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```
<DayPickerInput 
        placeholder={"Date..."} 
        onDayChange={day => setNewDate(day)}
/>
```

And here is the DOM structure for the day picker

[image]

Comment: Is the fact that you use -wraper instead of -wrapper just a typo here on SO or is that the actual problem with your code?

Comment: It was a typo and fixing it made it work

Answer (score 1):

In your example the class you're targetting is 'DayPicker-wraper' while the DOM seems to have the classname as 'DayPicker-wrapper'. Alternatively, could you not also add a className like so then target that?

```
<DayPickerInput 
    className='date-picker'
    placeholder={"Date..."} 
    onDayChange={day => setNewDate(day)}
/>
```